# How can i read from a FileWriter

Tags: java, ajax

i have a serious problem with my program. I need to read from a filewriter.

Let me explain the problem.Firstly, i want a file(with extension P) and i want to encrypt this data to a file (with extension C) .After this , i want to decrypt the data from file C to D.But the problem is that C is "stored" as file writer and i cannot read from it.How can i do that?

Comment: Can we have a code example?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. FileWriter is for writing, not reading. Obviously.